# How to change the notation of mathematica's output?

Tags: functions, output-formatting

If Mathematica intends to output an elementary function, it will output them in the form of $f(x)$. Like if its output should be a power function, it outputs $a^x$; nevertheless, I don't like the notation; instead of outputting $a^{bx}$, I want it to output $\exp_a\circ\left(b\cdot\mathrm{id}\right)$ (while $\mathrm{id}$ is the identical function). Could you tell me whether there is any way to achieve this?

Comment: How can $a^{b x}$ become $\text{exp}_a\otimes(b\cdot\text{id})$? Where did the $x$ go?

Comment: @Roman function is a set of tuples, not a number, while $a^{bx}$ is a number (btw, instead outputting $a^{bx}$, I want it to output $\exp_a\cric\left(b\cdot\mathrm{id}\right)$)

Comment: @Roman I believe one is to think of it implicitly as a function of $x$, namely `Function[x, a^(b x)]`, and decompose it into function operations (composition of {exponential[base $a$], scalar-multiplication[by $b$] of identity}) -- at least notationally as output. It's not a natural way to express a function in *Mma*. I mean, *Mma* does not decompose functions this way. How to get something like `Composition[a^#&, Composition[b #&, Identity]]`, but!: `Composition[b # &, Identity]` does not accurately express scalar mult., and `Composition[b # &, Identity]` automatically evaluates to `b # &`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually, what I meant by $\exp_a\circ\left(b\cdot \mathrm{id}\right)$ is the function which satisfied with $exp_a\circ\left(b\cdot\mathrm{id}\right)=a^{bx}$. Not $\exp_a\circ\left(b\circ\mathrm{id}\right)$

Comment: I didn't write $b \circ \text{id}$.  I wrote more or less something equivalent to $\times_b \circ \text{id}$, mentioned Mathematica does not have a "$b \cdot -$" operator or literally, that it "does not accurately express scalar mult."

Comment: There is a typo in previous comment,Actually, what I meant by $exp_\circ(\cdot id)$ is the function which satisfied with $\_\circ(\cdot id)(x)=^{}$. Not exp∘(∘id)

Comment: @MichaelE2 What about the mult of functions?

Comment: No, nor the addition of functions either. Unless you count `Through[(f*g)[x]]` and `Through[(f+g)[x]]`. (There is a question about problems with `Through[(f-g)[x]]` somewhere on this site already.)